# Convert SList to Dataframe

Tags: list, pandas, binaryfiles

I am reading data from a binary .out file using a python module "SWMMToolbox." The command to read the infilration time series for RG1 from the file.out is as follows:

```
x = !swmmtoolbox extract 'file.out' subcatchment,RG1,Infiltration_loss
```

See [link](https://timcera.bitbucket.io/swmmtoolbox/docsrc/_function_autosummary/swmmtoolbox.swmmtoolbox.extract.html) for details about swmmtoolbox.

The data type of 'x' is a 'IPython.utils.text.SList'
The data looks like this:
[image]

I would like to import this Slist into pandas, but am having trouble. I want to get the datetime string as one column and the value after the comma as another. However, when I use

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=x)
```

I get the following:
[image]

I also tried to use

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(x)
```

but get this:

[image]

I tried to use pd.read_csv, but I couldn't get it to work since 'x' is a variable and not a file.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(data=x).str.split(',',expand=True)

Comment: Great suggestion! I got the following error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: pd.DataFrame(data=x)[0].str.split(',',expand=True)

Comment: This worked: df[0].str.split(',',expand=True). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @LCook What exactly worked, can you please write the entire line?

Comment: @AndreiȚăranu, for example, slist = !swmmtoolbox extract $path_file subcatchment,R1,Rainfall; df = pd.DataFrame(data=slist); df = df[0].str.split(',',expand=True); df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0])

Comment: Trying to do the same thing, @LCook but getting an error. df[0] returns an error as well. I am running py3.8. Did pandas change how this works since you were successful perhaps? df.to_string works but I unable t then split.